AWS DMS Serverless Replication - getting no permission to access custom kms key while processing a RDS source encrypted with custom kms key
Getting below error while running Serverless DMS with AWS postgres RDS source encrypted with custom kms key.

Test connection failed for endpoint 'pgdb' and replication config
'otp-trig-rep'. Failure Message: 'No permission to access Key
'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:59018XXXXXXX:key/8743xxxx-c8xx-4fxx-8bxx-1154xxxxxxxx'''

Since, DMS serverless uses service linked role AWSServiceRoleForDMSServerless - which can't be modified, i tried providing all permissions to this role in the custom kms key policy.  Still i'm getting above error.
Custom key policy snippet:
{
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::5901XXXXXXXX:role/aws-service-role/dms.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForDMSServerless",
               ]
},
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
}

Could anyone please suggest what am i missing, how can this be achieved.

I was fighting the same problem until I reviewed the auto-created kms key aliased aws/dms in an account with an existing replication instance.
After I have added these statements to my custom kms key, the permission problem got resolved.
Note how the star-principal is restricted to the same account.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "auto-dms-1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access through DMS for all principals in the account that are authorized to use DMS",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:ListGrants",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "kms:ViaService": "dms.<REGION>.amazonaws.com",
                    "kms:CallerAccount": "<ACCOUNT>"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow direct access to key metadata to the account",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT>:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:RevokeGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

From the docs:

Unlike other AWS resource policies, an AWS KMS key policy does not
automatically give permission to the account or any of its identities.
To give permission to account administrators, the key policy must
include an explicit statement that provides this permission, like this
one.

Also from docs:

Unless the key policy explicitly allows it, you cannot use IAM
policies to allow access to a KMS key. Without permission from the key
policy, IAM policies that allow permissions have no effect.

